# Как вывести два списка с новой строки, а не в одной

Tags: java, arraylist

Суть задачи вывести отдельно гласные буквы и согласные из введенной строки, у меня эти два списка выводятся в одну строку,обязательным пуктом стоит,что Программа должна выводить две строки.

```
public class Solution {
    public static char[] vowels = new char[]{'а', 'я', 'у', 'ю', 'и', 'ы', 'э', 'е', 'о', 'ё'};

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Введите строку ");
        String text = reader.readLine();
        while (text.contains(" ")){
            String rep = text.replace(" ","");
            text =rep;

        }

        char[] texts = text.toCharArray();


        List<Character> onlyvowels = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Character> withoutvowels = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
            if (isVowel(texts[i])) {
                onlyvowels.add(texts[i]);
            }

            else {
                withoutvowels.add( texts[i] );
            }

        }

        for (Character x : onlyvowels ){
            System.out.print( x + " ");//вывод первого списка
        }


        for (Character y : withoutvowels ){
            System.out.print(  + y + " " );//вывод второго списка
        }

    }



    // метод проверяет, гласная ли буква
    public static boolean isVowel(char character) {
        character = Character.toLowerCase(character);  // приводим символ в нижний регистр - от заглавных к строчным буквам
        for (char vowel : vowels) {  // ищем среди массива гласных
            if (character == vowel) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Нужно добавить перевод строки после вывода первого списка, например так:

```
System.out.print("\n");
```

или так:

```
System.out.println();
```

Comment: Понял,спасибо Вам большое!

Comment: Если ответ помог, вы можете отметить его принятым, для этого поставьте галку слева от ответа.